# Facebook Comments Moderation View for external links

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-comments

I am developing an app on Facebook. I am adding the comments section to each video page and the data-href = "http://www.mysite.com/myvideourl". When I do this, the comments show up but the moderator view doesn't show up. However, if I set the data-href = "http://apps.facebook.com/myapp" the moderator view shows up. I have added the following to the page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<meta property="fb:admins" content="63987xxxx"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1773276957xxxxx"/>
```

Any thoughts/help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by moderator view showing up ? According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/, the moderation view is on facebook - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments. And by adding the fb:app_id, you are enabling all the moderators of the app to become moderators of the comments. Otherwise, you can moderate comments inline.

Comment: I am actually the developer of the APP. I am unable to see the moderator view when I add comments to url. But I think its because the videos are located in a different domain than the ones I gave in the app details. Think I found the answer!